# Regex Not Changing Output

Tags: regex, powershell, iis, httpwebrequest

**Problem**
I'm writing a PowerShell script to verify the HTTP status of some IIS web applications that I'm creating. I need to first determine the URL of the application so that I can run a HTTP request on it.

Using `Get-WebURL` and targeting the correct path, I am able to retrieve a summation of the information I am looking for:

> @{ResponseUri=http://localhost/WebApplication1/; Status=OK; Description=OK}

My regex is trying to pull the URL from this string. Using RegExr (http://regexr.com/), I tested the regex and validated that it works:
[image: online regex tester]

**Script** (some logic commented so I could focus on regex):

```
Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
       [string]$name,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=2)]
       [string]$site = "Default Web Site" #default value if none specified
 )

$path = "IIS:\Sites\$site\$name"
$url = Get-WebURL -PSPath $path

$urlFound = '/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/igm'
$urlNew = $url -replace $urlFound,'$1'
$urlWTF = $url -match $urlFound

#$httpRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("$urlNew") #create request
#$httpResponse = $httpRequest.GetResponse() #get response from site
#$httpStatus = [int]$httpResponse.StatusCode #get HTTP code as an integer

if ($httpStatus -eq 200) #if code = 200
{
     ("*** '{0}' is OK ***`n" -f ($path) ) | write-host -ForegroundColor Blue
}else
{
     ("*** '{0}' may be down ***`n" -f ($path) ) | write-host -ForegroundColor Red
}

Write-host $url 
Write-Host $urlNew
Write-Host $urlWTF
#$httpResponse.Close() #clean the HTTP request
```

**Output:**
[image]

--My Regex is just repeating the '$url' value. It also shows no match.--

**Question**
I have been trying many examples from Stack Overflow and various online sources, but nothing has seemed to work.
Is there anything evident that I am missing here that could be causing my regex to remain idle? I'm stumped at this point.

Comment: not tested, but you might try replacing `$url = Get-WebURL -PSPath $path` with `$url = (Get-WebURL -PSPath $path).ResponseUri`

Comment: Or you could strip the curly bracket, split on `;`, and use `ConvertFrom-StringData`. Something like `($url.Trim('@{}').Split(';')|ConvertFrom-StringData).ResponseUri`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thanks as well! Though a bit more lengthy, it gets the job done just the same way.

Comment: @AnthonyStringer Thanks! Your method is much more simple and gets me exactly what I'm looking for. 

I appreciate all of the help, but I am still interested in finding out why the regex wasn't working if you guys have any pointers.